# Does SSL_CTX_free erase secrets from memory?

Tags: c++, openssl

Hello to the community,

I've got the following code :

```
int main()
{
    SSL_CTX* pCTX
...
    SSL_CTX_free(pCTX);
    pCTX = nullptr;
...
}
```

Are the all memory areas allocated by the SSL_CTX overwritten as a
result of SSL_CTX_free ?
I would like to be sure that there is no more sensitive information
allocated in memory

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Making sure that "no more sensitive information" remains in memory is OpenSSL's job. Your job is merely to tell OpenSSL that it's job is done, and it'll take care of securing its data.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but it's your job to make sure OpenSSL actually does it

Comment: I have changed the question title. If you think I made a mistake, feel free to change it back.

Comment: `pCTX = nullptr;` - unless you are going to be testing `pCTX` against `nullptr` later on, why bother?

Comment: There are a couple of aspects to consider here:  What SSL_CTX_free()'s documentation *promises* it will do, and what the function *actually does*.  Ideally they'd be the same thing, but in practice they may differ.  As for the former, I don't see anything in the man page ( https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_free.html ) that promises that the function will overwrite freed memory for security purposes, so I wouldn't rely on that happening unless you have some other guarantee that it will.  As for the latter, you could probably use a debugger to check memory contents and see.